# How do I change the position of the moving cursor for it to be over the object after importing that object to another blend file?

Tags: import, 3d-cursor

This is the upper part of the arm of a robot. In its original blend file the moving cursor is over the object.

[image]

After exporting that object as obj, and importing that obj to another Blender File, the moving cursor is far away from the object.

[image]

When I zoom in, the moving cursor not only isnt above the object, but it's out of the screen.

[image]

How do I change the position of the moving cursor for it to be over the object after importing that object to another blend file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

1. Select your object
2. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd>, and choose *Selection to Cursor* or you can choose *Cursor to Selection*.